# How can we add a logo in the email body with sending logo as attachment, in C# or PHP

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to send a mail using the C# language. I have one logo which I attach in the body of the email, but when I send the mail to anyone this logo is sent as an attachment, not in embedded format.

I want the logo to be sent in embedded format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upload LOGO IMAGE on web server.
and add logo image by tags.

**example**

```
<img src ="https://myhomepage.com/logo.png" />
```

If you don't have any web servers. 
you can use **AWS S3**, **Azure Storage** to delivery image easily.

or you can use

[cid](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/) to embed images from attachment files.

```
 <img src="cid:myimagecid"/>
```

But, It will not work on all email clients.